# Wordpress - Don't load functions.php on single page template

Tags: wordpress

I am building a super basic WordPress single page template with all plugins disabled using a few filters.

I am getting an error when I try to load the page because, in the functions.php file, it pulls several functions for an assortment of would-be-loaded plugins all done by a previous developer. Since they are disabled, processing stops with a fatal error.

Rather than replacing each spot with the function_exists check, is it possible to skip the loading of the functions.php file if it's on the singlular page template I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficulty is wp-settings.php always loads the template's function.php.

However, since the functions.php file is loaded almost at the very end of the WordPress processing I think you can use the action 'setup_theme' to take over the WordPress processing and do the remainder of the WordPress processing as wp-blog-header.php would have except skipping the loading of functions.php.

```
add_action( 'setup_theme', function() {
    if ( $use_my_singlular_page_template ) {
        // Define the template related constants.
        wp_templating_constants(  );

        // Load the default text localization domain.
        load_default_textdomain();

        $locale = get_locale();
        $locale_file = WP_LANG_DIR . "/$locale.php";
        if ( ( 0 === validate_file( $locale ) ) && is_readable( $locale_file ) )
            require( $locale_file );
        unset( $locale_file );

        /**
         * WordPress Locale object for loading locale domain date and various strings.
         * @global WP_Locale $wp_locale
         * @since 2.1.0
         */
        $GLOBALS['wp_locale'] = new WP_Locale();

        /**
         *  WordPress Locale Switcher object for switching locales.
         *
         * @since 4.7.0
         *
         * @global WP_Locale_Switcher $wp_locale_switcher WordPress locale switcher object.
         */
        $GLOBALS['wp_locale_switcher'] = new WP_Locale_Switcher();
        $GLOBALS['wp_locale_switcher']->init();

        /*
         * don't load theme's function.php

        // Load the functions for the active theme, for both parent and child theme if applicable.
        if ( ! wp_installing() || 'wp-activate.php' === $pagenow ) {
            if ( TEMPLATEPATH !== STYLESHEETPATH && file_exists( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
                include( STYLESHEETPATH . '/functions.php' );
            if ( file_exists( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' ) )
                include( TEMPLATEPATH . '/functions.php' );
        }
         */

        /**
         * Fires after the theme is loaded.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'after_setup_theme' );

        // Set up current user.
        $GLOBALS['wp']->init();

        /**
         * Fires after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent.
         *
         * Most of WP is loaded at this stage, and the user is authenticated. WP continues
         * to load on the {@see 'init'} hook that follows (e.g. widgets), and many plugins instantiate
         * themselves on it for all sorts of reasons (e.g. they need a user, a taxonomy, etc.).
         *
         * If you wish to plug an action once WP is loaded, use the {@see 'wp_loaded'} hook below.
         *
         * @since 1.5.0
         */
        do_action( 'init' );

        // Check site status
        if ( is_multisite() ) {
            if ( true !== ( $file = ms_site_check() ) ) {
                require( $file );
                die();
            }
            unset($file);
        }

        /**
         * This hook is fired once WP, all plugins, and the theme are fully loaded and instantiated.
         *
         * Ajax requests should use wp-admin/admin-ajax.php. admin-ajax.php can handle requests for
         * users not logged in.
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         */
        do_action( 'wp_loaded' );

        // do the remaining parts of wp-blog-header.php

        // Set up the WordPress query.
        wp();

        // Load the theme template.
        require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );

        // everything is done; must not return!
        exit();
    }
} );
```

Comment: This answers my question, but does not solve my problem. By removing the functions.php, I turned off the custom post type which caused other problems. I ended up having to allow a few plugins use several remove_action lines to remove what the plugin was adding. All in all, it works as expected now even if it's not exactly perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be to rename/backup the previous developers `functions.php` file, and then create a new empty `functions.php` file. For example using a bash shell terminal:

```
mv /wp-content/themes/your-theme-here/functions.php /wp-content/themes/your-theme-here/functions.php.bkup

touch /wp-content/themes/your-theme-here/functions.php
```

`mv` - is the move/rename command, first argument is the file to move (rename), second is where to move (rename) it to.

`touch` - provides a way of creating a new file.

You could then populate this new `functions.php` file with any functions your project still requires.